# How could I program a spider's walking movements?

Tags: java, processing, physics, motion

I'm programming a spider that should have realistic movement. Currently I'm using this site as reference for how the legs should move, but I'm unsure how to implement it.

http://www.mechanicalspider.com/comparison.html

I know that some of the points move in a sine wave motion assigned to an x or y value and the ones that rotate around a fixed point are straightforward, but I don't understand how the bottom two 'feet' points move in relation to the other points. I'm not looking for code here so much as an explanation of how this could be turned into code.

Don't hesitate to ask if I haven't been clear enough, thanks. I'm building this in Processing by the way.

Comment: Take a look at the Box2D physics engine for Flash. There are some demos, including a spider. It looks realistic to me. You can download the code: (You have to iterate over the demos to find the spider) http://box2dflash.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may read about **inverse kinematics**.

Comment: Thanks, I found an example for Processing, so this is just what I needed.

Heres the link:

http://idblab.blogspot.com/2008/10/inverse-kinematics-and-processing.html

Comment: Great :) If you also need any advices how to solve inverse kinematics problem, I may help :)